# Should I take the perk to create Plate Armor?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm a full 2H warrior and already spending perk points on 2H, Block, Heavy Armor plus Blacksmithing and Enchanting.
Should I get the perk to create Plate armor? In order to get it I should spend one in Elven Armor as well...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Plate armor has the same armor rating as Orcish armor (40 base armor) which has the same level requirement.  Plate is also **heavier** than Orcish.  Stick with the Heavy Armor path in Smithing.

Answer (score 1):

I made the mistake of getting the elven armor perk without realizing that type of armor really isn't going to be suiting my 2handed warrior build. It's just one perk but really you should stick to the heavy side until dragon.

Answer (score 1):

The Plate perk also allows one to build scale armor. I took the plate perk so I could create better armor for my followers who use light armor.  It's a personal decision.

Comment: Do they wear it? Lydia won't dress up in plate for me, only dwarven.

Comment: the Plate perk also allows for scale.  However I believe that Lydia prefers heavy, rather than light armor.

Comment: But *do they wear it*?

Comment: If its better than their current armor, they will.

Comment: Given that I tried to get Lydia to wear plate (carrying no other armour), I would say that you're speculating.

Comment: According to this, some people have a bug with Lydia who will wear the most expensive armor instead of the armor rating. http://www.gamespot.com/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/forum/question-about-lydia-and-mjolls-armor-61392960

Comment: Ok, fair enough.

Comment: Lydia may have heavy armor perks and lack light armor perks - making most heavy armor types better for her.

Comment: I have given my follower a few things to see what they put on. Then I will take away what they have on to make than pick something else until they had on something that I felt was fitting. Then, for the most part, they will keep that on unless I give them something more powerful. But often they put on things that do not fit their class or skills.